# Restricting Razor Page to Ad Group

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authentication, .net-core, razor

At its simplest level all I want to do is restrict a razor page to users that are only in a certain AD Group using the inbuilt dot net authorization & authentication objects. My project will not be making use of cookies or anything else.

I've made a new, basic web site with the following code snippets I pulled from the authentication docs. My program.cs:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

    // Add services to the container.
    builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
    builder.Services.AddAuthentication("Test");
    builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy("Test", policy =>
            policy.Requirements.Add(new InCorrectGroupRequirement()));
    });

    var app = builder.Build();

    // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
        // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
        app.UseHsts();
    }

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseStaticFiles();

    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.MapRazorPages();

    app.Run();
}
```

My authorization handler & requirement classes

```
public class InCorrectGroupAuthorizationHandler : AuthorizationHandler<InCorrectGroupRequirement>
{
    private readonly IHttpClientFactory _httpClientFactory;

    public InCorrectGroupAuthorizationHandler(IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory)
    {
        _httpClientFactory = httpClientFactory;
    }

    protected override async Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, InCorrectGroupRequirement requirement)
    {
        var userId = context.User.Identities.First();

        if (userId.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            if (userId.Name == "pass")
                context.Succeed(requirement);
        }
    }
}

public class InCorrectGroupRequirement : IAuthorizationRequirement
{
}
```

Finally the page with the authorize attribute:

```
[Authorize(Policy = "Test")]
public class PrivacyModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly ILogger<PrivacyModel> _logger;

    public PrivacyModel(ILogger<PrivacyModel> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public void OnGet()
    {
    }
}
```

Enable windows authentication is also turned on in the launchSettings.json

With the above I was wanting to test & confirm that I had set everything up correctly by checking against my username instead of an ad group. However, when I navigate to the page I'm getting the following message:

> InvalidOperationException: No authenticationScheme was specified, and there was no DefaultChallengeScheme found. The default schemes can be set using either AddAuthentication(string defaultScheme) or AddAuthentication(Action configureOptions).

I've been at this for a while yet I am unable to get past this error. I thought I was setting up a default with what I've presented but evidently I'm not. Could someone please show me what it is I'm missing, or point me in the direction of some docs that may help me?

The terminology and the multiple ways of doing things is only confusing me more when I try to google something more specific.

Comment: `builder.Services.AddAuthentication(NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddNegotiate();`?

Answer (score 0):

As @BenderBoy said, the error you faced is you doesn't set the windows authetnication for the application. So you you should use `builder.Services.AddAuthentication(NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme) .AddNegotiate();` instead of `builder.Services.AddAuthentication("Test");`.

Besides, you don't register the IAuthorizationHandler which let your handler will not work in your application.

So please add below codes inside the program.cs and then it will work well.

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, InCorrectGroupAuthorizationHandler>();
```